# Wine error, packages being held, help please :S

Tags: 14.04, package-management, dependencies

I am getting this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: udev : Depends: libudev1 (= 204-5ubuntu20.2) but 204-5ubuntu20.4 is to be installed E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Then I've tried to apt-get dist-upgrade and I a similar error:

```
The following packages have been kept back: libudev1 udev 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

What should I do? I am Using ubuntu 14.04 64 bits. The output of `sudo apt-get -f install` is:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Using ubuntu 14.04 I really need help guys, sry for double posting

Comment: This is not a wine error so much as a dependency issue. When you solve the dependency issue, the rest will follow.

Comment: how do I solve the dependencie issue?

Comment: Did you follow the information on the duplicate question? If you still could not manage to resolve the problem please go to this chat to see how to solve the issues: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16541/dependency-issues